# Debug SOAP call in PHP: An exception has been raised as a result of client data

Tags: php, api, soap, wsdl

I am working with the UPS api and am having a difficult time debugging. I am getting the following stack trace:

```
Details
Type: SoapFault
Message: An exception has been raised as a result of client data.
File: /Users/shawn/Documents/work/sites/Wingspan/kaleco/lib/SixString/Utilities/Ups.php
Line: 161
Trace

#0 /Users/shawn/Documents/work/sites/Wingspan/kaleco/lib/SixString/Utilities/Ups.php(161): SoapClient->__soapCall('ProcessShipment', Array)
#1 /Users/shawn/Documents/work/sites/Wingspan/kaleco/routes/ups.php(14): SixString\Utilities\Ups->getShipment()
#2 [internal function]: {closure}()
#3 /Users/shawn/Documents/work/sites/Wingspan/kaleco/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Router.php(172): call_user_func_array(Object(Closure), Array)
#4 /Users/shawn/Documents/work/sites/Wingspan/kaleco/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Slim.php(1222): Slim\Router->dispatch(Object(Slim\Route))
#5 /Users/shawn/Documents/work/sites/Wingspan/kaleco/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Middleware/Flash.php(86): Slim\Slim->call()
#6 /Users/shawn/Documents/work/sites/Wingspan/kaleco/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Middleware/MethodOverride.php(94): Slim\Middleware\Flash->call()
#7 /Users/shawn/Documents/work/sites/Wingspan/kaleco/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Middleware/SessionCookie.php(116): Slim\Middleware\MethodOverride->call()
#8 /Users/shawn/Documents/work/sites/Wingspan/kaleco/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Middleware/PrettyExceptions.php(67): Slim\Middleware\SessionCookie->call()
#9 /Users/shawn/Documents/work/sites/Wingspan/kaleco/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Slim.php(1174): Slim\Middleware\PrettyExceptions->call()
#10 /Users/shawn/Documents/work/sites/Wingspan/kaleco/public/index.php(6): Slim\Slim->run()
#11 {main}
```

Here is the block of code:

```
    try{
        $mode = array('soap_version' => 'SOAP_1_1',  'trace' => 1,'exceptions' => true );
        $client = new \SoapClient($wsdl , $mode);
        $client->__setLocation($endpointurl);

        $header = new \SoapHeader('http://www.ups.com/XMLSchema/XOLTWS/UPSS/v1.0','UPSSecurity',$this->upss);
        $client->__setSoapHeaders($header);

        if(strcmp($operation,"ProcessShipment") == 0 ) {
            $resp = $client->__soapCall('ProcessShipment',array($this->processShipment()));
            echo "Response Status: " . $resp->Response->ResponseStatus->Description ."\n";
            //print_r($client->__getLastRequest());
        }
        else if (strcmp($operation , "ProcessShipConfirm") == 0) {
            $resp = $client->__soapCall('ProcessShipConfirm',array($this->processShipConfirm()));
            echo "Response Status: " . $resp->Response->ResponseStatus->Description ."\n";
        }
        else {
            $resp = $client->__soapCall('ProcessShipeAccept',array($this->processShipAccept()));
            //get status
            echo "Response Status: " . $resp->Response->ResponseStatus->Description ."\n";
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($resp);
            echo "</pre>";
        }
    }
    catch(Exception $ex){
        print_r ($ex);
    }
```

Line 161 is in the above code, this is the actual line:

```
$resp = $client->__soapCall('ProcessShipConfirm',array($this->processShipConfirm()));
```

I am looking for a way to debug this. It does not appear to be reaching the `catch` block and I cannot seem to determine the cause of the exception.

Comment: What is your $endpointurl ? You are trying to track right ?

Comment: Did you find the solution for this issue? I am having the same issue and didn't find the fix yet.

Answer (score 4):

Try to catch exception with `SoapFault` and print its `detail` property.

```
try {

   $response = $client->$call( $params );

} catch (\SoapFault $fault) {

    //trigger_error("SOAP Fault: (faultcode: {$fault->faultcode}, faultstring: {$fault->faultstring})", E_USER_ERROR);
    var_dump($fault->faultcode);
    var_dump($fault->faultstring);
    var_dump($fault->detail);
    die('Errore chiamata webservice UPS');

}
```

refer to: http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-soap-fault.php

Comment: For me, the `detail` property contains the crucial information about what specifically is raising the exception.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the nuances of exception handling in PHP, but Soap exceptions are squirrely little buggers in C# as well. In Visual Studio's debugger, you can get at the details of unhandled exceptions right in the IDE. If you have an option to do this, look for the exception's `"detail"` XML Element, as this will contain the web service's message telling you what was borked with your request.

As for actually trapping the exception, there's an old but good article by @Jeff Atwood that — though written for (gasp) VB.NET — might still provide some insight into what makes Soap exceptions so, er... slippery: [Coding Horror | Throwing better SOAP exceptions](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/08/throwing-better-soap-exceptions.html)

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: For what it's worth, **UPS gives this error for bad tracking numbers**. Use a good (valid) tracking number and it corrected my issue.

Comment: There is no Tracking Number in the first request you send to them. Yet it still returns this error.

Answer (score 1):

UPS gives this error also for bad ShipFrom/CountryCode or ShipTo/CountryCode in Rates API. e.g. germany can't be rated. This can't found in the UPS dev docs.